# retrieve sales data that is only sold from the certain date to another date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm just learning SQL, using Postgres. I have fruit sales data, how can I retrieve fruit that is only sold from the certain date to another date. I use a query like this but error

```
SELECT product_name,
       min (purchase_date) AS purchase_date
FROM sales
where purchase_date not in (purchase_date <= '2021-01-01' and purchase_date >= '2021-01-10')
GROUP BY product_name
ORDER by product_name asc ;
```

Comment: `where purchase_date not in (purchase_date >= '2021-01-01' and purchase_date <= '2021-01-10')` is invalid. What are you triing to archive? maybe `purchase_date < '2021-01-01' and purchase_date > '2021-01-10')`?

Comment: Incomplete information. 1) What is the error? 2) What date range do you want the sales to be in? Add information as update to question. 3) Probably looking for `where purchase_date between '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-10'`.

Comment: i mean fruit that has never been sold other than 1-10 January 2021. and only been ever sold in 1-10 January 2021

Comment: Your comment does not match up with your query. You need  to provide some sample data and expected output. **As requested before add the information as update to question.**

Answer (score 0):

It is `BETWEEN` you're looking for, I presume.

```
where purchase_date between '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-10'
```

You used *negative* logic (invalid, though), so I guess that you're looking for fruits sold between 1st and 10t of January 2021.

Comment: no, i mean fruit that has never been sold other than 1-10 January 2021. and only been ever sold in 1-10 January 2021

Comment: Then just negate BETWEEN: `where purchase_date NOT between ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a simple select, as that doesn't care about what *other* rows are doing.  But you should be able to do it in a HAVING clause to filter out based on the aggregates:

```
SELECT product_name,
           min (purchase_date) AS purchase_date
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY product_name
    HAVING min (purchase_date)  >= '2021-01-01' and max(purchase_date) <= '2021-01-10'
    ORDER by product_name asc ;
```